# Verification of telephone numbers

Tags: phone-number

I have to add an automated telephone verification feature for my web application. That is when the customer clicks a button in the web interface, he/she should be called (customer's phone already in the database) and asked to enter some identification number in the telephone keypad and then the calling system should notify the results to a URL.

I am searching a service provider for this. Please give me some recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Tropo or Twilio would both be appropriate for your needs.